# azure python library equivalent of aws boto3

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have a sample code to create an EC2 instance using boto3 in python.
Is there an equivalent for creating the same for azure VM ?

I understand there is `pip install azure-mgmt-resource` - but is this all that's required to get the task (creation of VM with the respective networking tasks) done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand there is `pip install azure-mgmt-resource` - but is this all that's required to get the task (creation of VM with the respective networking tasks) done ?

To create a `VM` using a `Python script`, you may need the following module along with `azure-mgmt-resource`

```
azure.identity 
azure.mgmt.compute 
azure.mgmt.network
```

I created a `virtual machine` using `Python`. Here is the updated code

```py
    import os
    import random
    import string
    
    from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
    from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
    from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
    from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
    
    
    def main():
    
        SUBSCRIPTION_ID = "<SUB_ID>"
        GROUP_NAME = "vm-RG"
        VIRTUAL_MACHINE_NAME = "venkatvm"
        SUBNET_NAME = "vmsubnet"
        INTERFACE_NAME = "vminterface"
        NETWORK_NAME = "vmnetwork"
        # VIRTUAL_MACHINE_EXTENSION_NAME = "virtualmachineextension"
    
        your_password = 'A1_' + ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(8))
    
        # Create client
        # For other authentication approaches, please see: https://pypi.org/project/azure-identity/
        resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(
            credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
            subscription_id=SUBSCRIPTION_ID
        )
        network_client = NetworkManagementClient(
            credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
            subscription_id=SUBSCRIPTION_ID
        )
        compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(
            credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
            subscription_id=SUBSCRIPTION_ID
        )
    
        # Create resource group
        resource_client.resource_groups.create_or_update(
            GROUP_NAME,
            {"location": "eastus"}
        )
    
        # Create virtual network
        network_client.virtual_networks.begin_create_or_update(
            GROUP_NAME,
            NETWORK_NAME,
            {
                'location': "eastus",
                'address_space': {
                    'address_prefixes': ['10.0.0.0/16']
                }
            }
        ).result()
    
        subnet = network_client.subnets.begin_create_or_update(
            GROUP_NAME,
            NETWORK_NAME,
            SUBNET_NAME,
            {'address_prefix': '10.0.0.0/24'}
        ).result()
    
        # Create network interface
        network_client.network_interfaces.begin_create_or_update(
            GROUP_NAME,
            INTERFACE_NAME,
            {
                'location': "eastus",
                'ip_configurations': [{
                    'name': 'MyIpConfig',
                    'subnet': {
                        'id': subnet.id
                    }
                }]
            } 
        ).result()
    
        # Create virtual machine
        vm = compute_client.virtual_machines.begin_create_or_update(
            GROUP_NAME,
            VIRTUAL_MACHINE_NAME,
            {
              "location": "eastus",
              "hardware_profile": {
                "vm_size": "Standard_B8ms"
              },
              "storage_profile": {
                "image_reference": {
                  "sku": "2016-Datacenter",
                  "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
                  "version": "latest",
                  "offer": "WindowsServer"
                },
                "os_disk": {
                  "caching": "ReadWrite",
                  "managed_disk": {
                    "storage_account_type": "Standard_LRS"
                  },
                  "name": "myVMosdisk",
                  "create_option": "FromImage"
                },
                "data_disks": [
                  {
                    "disk_size_gb": "1023",
                    "create_option": "Empty",
                    "lun": "0"
                  },
                  {
                    "disk_size_gb": "1023",
                    "create_option": "Empty",
                    "lun": "1"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "os_profile": {
                "admin_username": "testuser",
                "computer_name": "myVM",
                "admin_password": your_password,
                "windows_configuration": {
                  "enable_automatic_updates": True  # need automatic update for reimage
                }
              },
              "network_profile": {
                "network_interfaces": [
                  {
                    "id": "/subscriptions/" + SUBSCRIPTION_ID + "/resourceGroups/" + GROUP_NAME + "/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/" + INTERFACE_NAME + "",
                    # "id": NIC_ID,
                    "properties": {
                      "primary": True
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
        ).result()
        print("Create virtual machine:\n{}".format(vm))
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

[image]

After running the code, the `virtual machine` has been created in the `Azure Portal`.

[image]

Reference :   [azure-samples-python-management](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-samples-python-management/blob/main/samples/compute/manage_virtual_machine.py)

Comment: Thank you for your response. The AWS boto3 code is taking under 20 seconds to complete creating a EC2 instances with its respective resources. But the Azure script is taking ~3 minutes to complete creating the VM. Why the vast difference ?

Comment: It depends on network bandwidth and selected region in Azure.

Comment: What do I have to modify to select a region that'll execute faster ?

Comment: You can select the nearest region, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/explore/global-infrastructure/geographies/#geographies